# Grails One form can have two actions?

Tags: forms, grails, submit

my form has got two buttons ... both for entirely different purpose.. so there is a necessity to have separate actions ... Is it possible? if not what is the best possible solution to deal with such problem...
Thanks is advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `<g:actionSubmit>` [tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html) allows you to have multiple submit buttons in a single form.

```
<g:form controller="test">
  <g:actionSubmit value="Submit to success" action="success"/>
  <g:actionSubmit value="Submit to delete" action="delete"/>
</g:form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`<g:actionSubmit/>`](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html) buttons to have a single grails form go to different actions.

```
<g:form method="post">
    ...
    <g:actionSubmit action="oneAction" value="One Action"/>
    <g:actionSubmit action="anotherAction" value="Another Action"/>
</g:form>
```

Clicking "One Action" would be handled by the `oneAction` action of the current controller; clicking "Another Action" would be handled by the `anotherAction` action of the current controller.

Comment: Would it be possible to have the second action be controlled by a different controller? If so how.

Comment: Not that I can find. I imagine it'd be tough given that the `<form>` is going to constrain where the request goes. You might end up having to do a couple of forms for that. You could possibly use URL mappings to re-map the controller/action of each to another controller, but that'd feel a little hacky to me.

Comment: That is what I am trying to avoid. I would like to stay clean and maintainable but I am trying to have the user submit one piece and be directed to another controller to finish the process. Perhaps there is a way to have the button submit the "Create" command and redirect the user to the next form?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you here, but if you want to submit and then redirect, you can just [redirect](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html) to the next step at the end of your controller action.

Comment: Your piece of advice helped me solve the issue. For my particular issue I needed to add a redirect in the corresponding service.

Answer (score 1):

A single form can have only one action.

You can change that action, dynamically, using JavaScript, but that adds a dependancy on JS.

Better is to have the form submit to a single URL and then do something along the lines of (pseudo code):

```
if (submit is foo) {
    process_form_with_foo_class()
} elseif (submit is bar) {
    process_form_with_bar_class()
} else {
    // Form was submitted without using a submit button
    // e.g. with enter, or JS.
    process_form_with_foo_class() // Let's use foo as the default
}
```

Comment: While true of regular HTML forms, Grails can do this with `<g:actionSubmit/>`s. It puts parameters in the request that cause it to get routed to the correct action.

Comment: @Rob — err … so Grails has a built in function that does what I just described?

Comment: It does. I guess my comment was only in reply to your first sentence (*"A single form can have only one action."*) - I really should have phrased my comment differently (probably in the words of your comment, i.e. *"Grails has a built-in..."*) :)

Comment: +1 Though, for the javascript option, which neither Don nor I mentioned.